Karabiner-Elements ignore input source
Is there a way to send same keycode with different input source languages with Karabiner-Elements complex modification rules?
I want to send ? (questionmark) symbol with same keyboard shortcut using different languages, e.g. "en" and "uk". So pressing right_option + semicolon result: ?.
Currently:
...
{
  "from": {
    "key_code": "semicolon",
    "modifiers": {
      "mandatory": ["right_option"]
    }
  },
  "to": [
    {
      "key_code": "slash",
      "modifiers": ["left_shift"]
    }
  ],
  "type": "basic"
}
...

After switching to "uk" input source:
"input_source": {
   "input_source_id": "com.apple.keylayout.Ukrainian-PC",
   "language": "uk"
}

same combination output , (comma) - not what is expected.
Tried to use https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/json/complex-modifications-manipulator-definition/conditions/input-source/ with input_source_if field - but could not accomplish what's expected.
Edit:
What is it for?
I need symbol layer to be equally accessible from botch input source (probably more inputs sources in future) without making duplicated complex modification rules with multiple conditions statements like this:
"conditions": [
  {
    "type": "input_source_if",
    "input_sources": [
      {
        "language": "uk"
      }
    ]
  }
]

Also in ukraine layout shift+/ is not mapped to ?. So I've to remap each individual symbol like so: ukr= shift+7, eng = shift+/

What you mean by new input source? I need symbol layer to be equally accessible from botch input source.
